# Remove spaces only before and after commas

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am looking for a regex (?) way to remove spaces before and after commas only. Example:

```
((100 0, 101 0, 101 1, 100 1, 100 0)        ,  (100.2 0.2, 100.8 0.2, 100.8 0.8, 100.2 0.8, 100.2 0.2))
```

Expected result:

```
((100 0,101 0,101 1,100 1,100 0),(100.2 0.2,100.8 0.2,100.8 0.8,100.2 0.8,100.2 0.2))
```

I could not yet find a satisfactory answer despite numerous searches.

Comment: Without `Regex`, you can do `str.Replace(", ",",").Replace(" ,",",")`

Comment: Thought about this but does it work for "     ,   " - sorry SO swallowed up this example ...

Comment: Yes it will work. But, it will not work if there are multiple spaces. For that see @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, " *, *", ",");
```

This searches for every comma preceded and/or followed by any number of spaces, and replaces the comma and spaces with just a comma.

Here's a demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nlr1Z0)

Answer (score 6):

Using `Regex`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
    input,
    @"\s*,\s*",
    ",");
```

Using `string.Split`, `Trim` and `Join`:

```
var result = string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray());
```

Split the string first, trim each part, join together again. Much faster than regular expressions (around 8x faster on my PC).

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to match `@"\s*,\s*"`, and replace it with `","`:

```
var s = Regex.Replace(orig, @"\s*,\s*", ",");
```

`\s` stands for "whitespace". It will replace spaces, tabs, vertical tabs, and so on. Asterisk qualifier is greedy, so the expression will match as many spaces as possible, both before and after the comma.