# How to validate comma separated string with space using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need to validate comma separated string using regex,but I have two problem.

My sample input as follows,

```
ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7 - Valid

ERW SW1,ERW SW2,ASA,S4,ERW SW5,ERW SW6,ERWSW7 - Valid(space between word should valid)

ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7, - Invalid - Comma at end

,ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7 - Invalid - Comma at beginning

ERWSW1,ERWSW2,,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7 - Invalid - No value between 2,3 comma
```

I wrote following Regex to validate the input

```
^([a-z A-Z0-9 !@#$%?=*&-]+,)*[a-z A-Z0-9 !@#$%?=*&\s-]+$
```

**First problem is** when space between the commas showing as a valid string.

```
Eg: ERWSW1, ,   ,ERWSW2,ASA,S4
```

I need to avoid that, how can I do it?

**And my second problem is**, I also need to remove extra space from the string. two remove extra space I need function.(***this is not related to above regex***)

```
Input: ERWSW1 ,  ERW SW2,ASA ,S4 ,ERW SW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7
```

I need the following output,

```
RWSW1,ERW SW2,ASA,S4,ERW SW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7
```

**Updated :**

for my second problem, I wrote the following code,

```
string str = " ERW SW1 , ERW SW2 , ASA";
var ss = Regex.Replace(str, " *, *", ",");
```

But it's not removing spaces properly, I need this output

```
ERW SW1,ERW SW2,ASA
```

Comment: Why regex? Is it an assignment? This is really easy to solve using `string.Split`. `var values = input.Split(','); var validFormat = !values.Any(i => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i));`

Comment: @InBetween A regex appraoch also allows for checking that all the values are of valid characters, and that no values are empty

Comment: @InBetween I need to validate first problem using regex, second problem can be anything sir. yes this is part of my assignment

Comment: @CertainPerformance you can do the same with split too, I fail too see the limitations you seem to imply. Its an assignment though so no use discussing the issue.

Comment: First problem has been solved many times, [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294787/regular-expression-repeating-pattern-delimited-by-comma). for example. Removing spaces around commas is also a frequent problem, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454971/remove-spaces-only-before-and-after-commas).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please look my updated question and please provide me answer for both issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a character class specifying what you would allow to match. For the spaces between the words you could use a repeating group preceded with a space.

```
^[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*(?:,[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*)*$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%29*%28%3f%3a%2c%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%29*%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=ERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERW+SW1%2cERW+SW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERW+SW5%2cERW+SW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%2c%0d%0a%2cERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2c%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1+%2c++ERW+SW2%2cASA+%2cS4+%2cERW+SW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERW*SW1%2cERW-SW2%2cA.SA%0d%0a+ERWSW1+%2c+ERWSW2+%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5+%0d%0a&o=m)

To remove the spaces around the comma's, you could match the string including the spaces and comma  `*, *` and then replace the comma's surrounded by spaces with a single comma.

```
^ *[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*(?: *, *[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*)* *$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e+*%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%29*%28%3f%3a+*%2c+*%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a+%5b%5cw!%40%23%24%25%3f%3d*%26.-%5d%2b%29*%29*+*%5cr%3f%24&i=ERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERW+SW1%2cERW+SW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERW+SW5%2cERW+SW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%2c%0d%0a%2cERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1%2cERWSW2%2c%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERWSW1+%2c++ERW+SW2%2cASA+%2cS4+%2cERW+SW5%2cERWSW6%2cERWSW7%0d%0aERW*SW1%2cERW-SW2%2cA.SA%0d%0a+ERWSW1+%2c+ERWSW2+%2cASA%2cS4%2cERWSW5+%0d%0a&o=m) | [C# demo](https://tio.run/##pZLfT8IwEMef17/irGjWWZZo/JFICBDDg4m8MBIeEJM6CzQZ27IriiH722fHBo6ZEI19ud7tPr1v16@PTT9KZJatUIVz8D5Ry2WLVDN3JNfaHcr5KhBJfx0nElFFIbYIkHj1Gigf/EAgwkiiJhtilUXUQpvwHqk3GAgV2oxY5quFOjGHT6ZQbBDasCFQWbQ/HHvjS74NV7zn9bh3XWQ3Rbgtwh3lP0AoSThEoWThKPy7qbxO8v8IroB/J4EDVC4LhobqdY/yTjm6uaVdr1fvgf2QQiAcCgS6b09zM@yS4l0hFlrLJDTP26Uv4EyeP066p42zTts5d5vTC7tzD/Uac/Kqw3/bzRxwGrQ6e2bMLPwF2F4hAkGFO6Oxms/UDGxja7l2H3EgtL@wke9Us3pzvh6M66NAuuNEafmkQlniQxkHwpc5TrfqqdlwytxRopY2Y62Dk9Lvv0aslKRZ9gU)

*Code example*

```
string[] strings = {
    "ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7",
    "ERW SW1,ERW SW2,ASA,S4,ERW SW5,ERW SW6,ERWSW7",
    "ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7,",
    ",ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7",
    "ERWSW1,ERWSW2,,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7",
    "ERWSW1 ,  ERW SW2,ASA ,S4 ,ERW SW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7",
    "ERW*SW1,ERW-SW2,A.SA",
    " ERWSW1 , ERWSW2 ,ASA,S4,ERWSW5 "
};

string pattern = @"^ *[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*(?: *, *[\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+(?: [\w!@#$%?=*&.-]+)*)* *$";

foreach (String s in strings) {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern)) {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, " *, *", ",").Trim());
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7
ERW SW1,ERW SW2,ASA,S4,ERW SW5,ERW SW6,ERWSW7
ERWSW1,ERW SW2,ASA,S4,ERW SW5,ERWSW6,ERWSW7
ERW*SW1,ERW-SW2,A.SA
ERWSW1,ERWSW2,ASA,S4,ERWSW5
```

Comment: this for which problem sir? can you please explain this. I need two seperate answers for both problems sir

Comment: and the problem is when  input is `ERWSW1 ,ERWSW2 ,ASA` .your code is showing as invalid input. I need to allow it, but need to reomove that extra spaces using another function

Comment: You can match the pattern with the spaces and then replace the spaces `^\w+(?: \w+)*(?: *, *\w+(?: \w+)*)*$` after with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/KP7q7W/1

Comment: Sir I wrote this (`var ss = Regex.Replace(str, " *, *", ",");`) code to remove thar extra space from the string. But the problem is when `" ERW SW1 , ERWSW2,ASA"` which returns `" ERW SW1,ERWSW2,ASA"`. First space not removing

Comment: and other problem is your code, special charcters not allow, I need to allow it also. Eg `ERW*SW1,ERW-SW2,A.SA`:

Comment: Ik will take a look at it

Comment: Thank you sir, please help me

Comment: Sir I looked at your code, ` ERWSW1 , ERWSW2 ,ASA,S4,ERWSW5 ` but this kind of input(`space before first word and space after last word`) showing as invalid.

Comment: And sir, `Regex.Replace(s, " *, *", ",")` this code part not removing space when space before first word and space after the last word ` ERWSW1 , ERWSW2 ,ASA,S4,ERWSW5 `

Comment: To match the pattern with leading and trailing spaces, you could optionally match them and then use trim to remove the leading and trailing spaces. I will update the answer.

Comment: can you please tell me, how to allow you are given regex when input is empty as well? is it possible to do sir?

Comment: If you want to check for an empty string, you don't have to use a regex. Just Use for example .Trim() on the string and check `== ""`

Comment: no no sir, I need your Regex to validate `string str = "ERW*SW1,ERW-SW2,A.SA";` , I mean I also need that regex to allow input string when `string str = ""` beacause When I pass empty string your regex vaidate it as wrong input

Comment: Should it also be valid when there are multiple whitespaces or really only `""`

Comment: its for only `""`

Comment: You could make the whole pattern optional https://regex101.com/r/UfzxTh/1

Comment: Okay sir, Thanks for your help